# Javafx panel doesn't appear on a frame created using netbeans gui builder

Tags: java, swing, javafx

I have a swing Application that extends javax.swing.JFrame.
I built this using NetBeanse GUI builder.
and I wanted to add a Bar chart to this program using JavaFX, so I got a sample code from Oracle and changed it according to my requirements, Oracle example(http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/swing/swing-fx-interoperability.htm#CHDIEEJE).
The problem is that when I run this class it shows the frame and the jPanel are there but it doesn't display the JavaFX panel for some reason.

my code:

```
public class Guage extends javax.swing.JFrame {
/**
 * Creates new form Guage
 */
public Guage() {

    initComponents();

} 

private static void initFX(JFXPanel fxPanel) {
    // This method is invoked on the JavaFX thread
    Scene scene = createScene();
    fxPanel.setScene(scene);

}

private static Scene createScene() {
    Group  root  =  new  Group();
    Scene  scene  =  new  Scene(root, Color.ALICEBLUE);
        XYChart.Series TotallyPositive = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series TotallyNegative = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series MixedPositive = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series MixedNegative = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series MixedNeutral = new XYChart.Series();
    XYChart.Series Neutral = new XYChart.Series(); 

    allSeries.add(TotallyPositive);
    allSeries.add(TotallyNegative);
    allSeries.add(MixedPositive);
    allSeries.add(MixedNegative);
    allSeries.add(MixedNeutral);
    allSeries.add(Neutral);

    final CategoryAxis xAxis = new CategoryAxis();
    final NumberAxis yAxis = new NumberAxis();
    final BarChart<String,Number> bc = 
        new BarChart<>(xAxis,yAxis);
    bc.setTitle("Summary");
    xAxis.setLabel("Tweets");       
    yAxis.setLabel("Value");
    bc.setAnimated(false);
     TotallyPositive.setName("Totally Positive"); 
    TotallyNegative.setName("Totally Negative");
    MixedPositive.setName("Mixed Positive");
    MixedNegative.setName("Mixed Negative");
    MixedNeutral.setName("Mixed Neutral");
    Neutral.setName("Neutral");     


    TotallyPositive.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Totally Positive", 
    KacstV2.TP));
    TotallyNegative.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Totally Negative", 
    KacstV2.TN));
    MixedPositive.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mixed Positive", 
    KacstV2.MP));
    MixedNegative.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mixed Negative", 
    KacstV2.MN));
    MixedNeutral.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Mixed Neutral", 
    KacstV2.MNeutral));  
    Neutral.getData().add(new XYChart.Data("Neutral", KacstV2.N));  
  bc.getData().addAll(TotallyPositive,TotallyNegative,MixedPositive,MixedNegative,MixedNeutral,Neutral);


    root.getChildren().add(bc);


    return (scene);
}

private static void initAndShowGUI() {
    // This method is invoked on the EDT thread

    final JFXPanel fxPanel = new JFXPanel();

    new Guage().jPanel1.add(fxPanel);


    Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            initFX(fxPanel);
        }
   });
}
```

and here is how I Run the code in my main method:

```
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
             new Guage().setVisible(true);
            initAndShowGUI();
        }
    });
```

any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Any particular reason to mix `Swing` with `JavaFx` ?

Comment: yes, I need to show a bar chart with other swing components

Comment: so why use `JavaFx` ? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873878/creating-a-simple-bar-chart-in-java-reads-data-and-outputs-bar-graph    or http://blue-walrus.com/2014/03/bar-chart-in-java-swing/