# Java Swing how to display graphics component inside JPanel

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, graphics, jlabel

I have an app with the following layout:
[image]

After I click the next screen button, it will hide all the components and several pie and bar charts should appear.

All this code is in my `GUI` class, then I have a different class, called the `PieChart` class similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29873878/creating-a-simple-bar-chart-in-java-reads-data-and-outputs-bar-graph) which generates the chart using the `Java Graphics` How can I call this class and display the graph inside a Panel or inside my frame? Thank you!

Comment: Don't remove or rebuild JPanels.  Use the Swing [CardLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/card.html) to switch from one JPanel to the next JPanel.

Comment: If you don't want to use a layout manager then you can have two jPanels that fill the jFrame entirely each with its own child components, and you can simply hide/show the one you need using `yourPanel.setVisible(true/false);` Note that the example you linked can easily be placed inside a jPanel rather than a jFrame.

Comment: *"Following this.."* Ask another question. @GilbertLeBlanc has suggested the optimal way to switch from the GUI seen above, to the graphic. Get that sorted first. Aside: I'm voting to close this because it has two questions. I'll remove that close vote if the 2nd is edited out.

Comment: @AndrewThompson thanks for heads-up, I deleted the first question so that my post is more relevant, the main intention of my post stays the same, I'd like to know how I can display the chart inside a label or frame, thanks

Comment: @sorifiend and then for the actual graphics, do I just do ```BarChart barChart = new BarChart``` and then ```myPanel.add(barChart)``` ? Thanks

Comment: @GilbertLeBlanc thank you so much, CardLayout seems really useful, I will use that

Comment: @Samuel V. Yes, assuming your bar chart extends a swing component like a jPanel, then you could do that.

Answer (score 0):

If the PieChart extends a component then it can simply be placed into a panel for example `chartPanel.add(chart);`, then you can use a card layout or you can manually toggle visibility as mentioned in the comments. Here is a basic example of changing the visibility of components:

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame("Demo");
JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
JPanel chartPanel = new JPanel();
JButton button = new JButton("View Chart");

frame.add(mainPanel);
frame.add(chartPanel);
mainPanel.add(button);
chartPanel.setVisible(false);

//Add event to create asd show the pie chart
button.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        //Remove any previous chart
        chartPanel.removeAll();

        //Create and add new chart based on data
        PieChart chart = new PieChart(yourData);
        chartPanel.add(chart);
    
        //Hide the main panel with the buttons, and show the chart panel instead
        chartPanel.setVisible(true);
        mainPanel.setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Note that you would need to add another button to the chartPanel so that you can swap back to the main panel if needed.

Comment: One advantage of using a `CardLayout` is that it (the panel with the card layout) will return a preferred size as tall as the tallest card & as wide as the widest.